# What is the query in sqlite3 for retrieving data month-wise

Tags: iphone, date, sqlite

I am struck with a problem. I have used sqlite3 for inserting, saving and retrieving data. I am aware of the query to retrieve data, i.e

```
 SELECT * from tableName.
```

But I have a date saved for every reminder and the format I saved was @"MMMM dd", it is saved as January 23,March 14 etc. It's actually in a from that contains a row with textfield. When clicked a date picker appears,with date, month and year. But after selecting the date format displayed would be as mentioned!

I have successfully displayed all the reminders in view all, group wise by using query:

```
SELECT * from tableName WHERE grp = 'Family'|'Office' etc...
```

but I have a requirement: In view monthly I need to display month wise reminders based on row(month) selected in picker view.I have tried the following query:

```
  SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE Date = 'January'
```

but it is not working but when I give Date = 'January 17' it is displaying the reminder, because I have saved a reminder with that date. It cannot be the case because we are not aware of date the user enters exactly. I have gone through several links for the solution. Some came up with a suggestion to save Date as DATETIME,but when I used it, it displayed failed to create table.Now when I deleted the app frm simulator and made it run again,its getting saved.None of the 3 answers below worked,please help me with valuable suggestions,

Can anyone suggest me a query that will do the trick,

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the tactic for retrieving data or all rows corresponding to a particular month.

1. Firstly save the date format as "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
2. Then retrieve the data of a particular month

For more information here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8725685/retrieve-month-part-from-date-saved-in-sqlite-database-table-for-displaying-mont)

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I think `select * from tableName where Date like "<yourmonth>%"`, where you replace  with the value returned from the picker. Honestly, though, storing it as a DATETIME would make these types of queries easier (and perhaps faster). You would have to drop the existing table and create a new table with a type of "DATETIME".

Comment: Its not working I saved Date as DATETIME,but the query is not working,please help me,thanks in advance :)

Comment: If you changed it to a DATETIME, you'll need to change the query to be `select * from tableName where MONTH(Date) = <yourmonth>.

Comment: Waiting for your reply,I have a view where the user fills all the data,in that there is one field for date,I have set mode of datpicker to datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate,then after selecting date,I have set the display mode as "MMMM dd".Then he clicks save,now the user views reminder

There I have month wise reminder display.I did what all you suggested,changed to DATETIME,then select * from tableName where Date like MONTH(Date) = <monthName %>,please suggest me how to fix it,please,Now we have power cut,ll get back after 1 hr,txs for patience and concern :)

Comment: No, just `MONTH(Date) = 'Jan'`

Comment: Yeah implemented that too,but not working,shall I place the code,thanks

Comment: Hi Mr.jknupp,sorry If I am interrupting again and again,please suggest me a way...thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE Date LIKE 'January%'
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from tablename where Date like  '< month >%' , where month is value of month selected form datepicker.

Comment: Sorry lost net connection,thanks for the answer but its not working,please suggest me some other way,thanks in advance :)